# Wrapping Javascript Library in a React Component Using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I would like to use the [Editor.JS](https://editorjs.io) library inside my Gatsby site (using, of course, React).  On the [getting started page](https://editorjs.io/getting-started), it states that I should import and initial EditorJS as follows:

```
import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs';


const editor = new EditorJS();
```

I would like to set up this basic configuration on a `edit.js` page that I have set up on my Gatsby site.  Or, put otherwise, I need to somehow or other wrap this in a react component.

I saw a solution somewhere that uses a class based React component and React life cycles, but I am new to React and have not used class based components yet (as I prefer to use React hooks instead).

As such, I would like to know how I can do this using React Hooks.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, if you have an example where somebody uses react class components and having this doc https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#from-classes-to-hooks  you can try to convert the example by yourself. It will definitely help you with understanding of react. I hope this helps to start.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look - but if someone knows how to do this simple example that I published here, I'd appreciate an answer.

Comment: To explain further -- the solution I saw is for a much more complete implementation of EditorJS.  I want to start with the most basic implementation and see how it is done.  It's hard to learn from an advanced example.

Comment: DId you have luck with this?